# a:hover not working properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress to create a website (Using the 2017 theme).  I added a link by adding the following HTML:

```
<a href="www." target="_blank"><span style="color: #0000ff;">text</span></a>
```

then I had to get rid of Wordpress underline, by adding this CSS:

```
.entry-content a, .entry-summary a, .taxonomy-description a, .logged-in-as a, .comment-content a, .pingback .comment-body > a, .textwidget a, .entry-footer a:hover, .site-info a:hover {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

my next goal is to have the hypertext change color when someone is hovering over it and so far I have done this in the CSS:

```
a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

The problem is; the background color was originally `#def`, and it worked when hovering, but the text color remained blue `#0000ff`.  I tried adding `!important` to it and I even tried making it red `#FF0000`.

I even went back into the html to delete the color of the text to see if it was giving priority to the blue html instead of the red CSS, but even the plain black text wouldn't change to red when I hover over it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: this seems to be an issue with css specificity, your inline style of span has higher precedence over your pseudo-element :hover

Comment: @luciferous That is not specificity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the span color because you have an inline style forcing the span color or remove that and use only CSS.

Example:

```css
.entry-content a, .entry-summary a, .taxonomy-description a, .logged-in-as a, .comment-content a, .pingback .comment-body > a, .textwidget a, .entry-footer a:hover, .site-info a:hover {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

a:hover, a:hover span {
    color: black !important;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<a href="www." target="_blank"><span style="color: #0000ff;">text</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

Please Remove span `style="color: #0000ff;"`

then you can add **span:hover**

```
span:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/kvbdLszf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because of this line.

```
<a href="www." target="_blank"><span style="color: #0000ff;">text</span></a>
```

Inline styling get a higher priority than css in a css file.
Try adding this instead

html

```
<a href="www." target="_blank"><span>text</span></a>
```

css

```
span{color:#0000FF}
```